# how to use python to list bucket in sub folder with limit IAM user permission

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have IAM user with policy like:

> ```
>   "Action": [
>     "s3:GetObject",
>     "s3:GetObjectAcl",
>     "s3:GetObjectTagging",
>     "s3:PutObject",
>     "s3:PutObjectAcl",
>     "s3:DeleteObject",
>     "s3:ListBucket"
>   ],
>   "Resource": [
>     "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/subfolder",
>     "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/subfolder/*"
>   ],
> ```

I can use this IAM user aws keys to put object in the bucket, but when I want to list this folder, I got `Access Denied`

> my_bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket')

```
for object_summary in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="bucket/subfolder/"):
    print(object_summary.key)
```

Any idea how to list objects with limit IAM user permission, thanks

Comment: I don't immediately see the problem, but, are you able to successfully make any boto3 calls to this bucket with this policy? like can you do a GetObject, for instance?

Comment: No, I can not get object , get_object_acl, I tried s3 recource and s3 client, I don't know why. The s3 bucket is belong to anther aws account and we did cross account access, IAM user belong to my aws account, and I ask the s3 account owner, they give as action:*, and my IAM user policy is showed as I post.

Comment: @DawidFieluba there is no policy action named s3:ListObjects. You use s3:ListBucket.

Comment: @Weever are you saying that you tried the S3 client call `list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix='subfolder/')` and it failed with AccessDenied?

Comment: @Weever access can be denied based on bucket policy as well. Ask the owner of bucket to verify that your principal is allowed in bucket policy.

Comment: @jarmod yes, lt got me access denied, I do not have permit at root bucket that config both on my IAM user and their bucket policy, but I do have access from `subfolder` and `subfolder\*`, the python code always return access denied and if I use Java aws jdk, I can list, get object acl, get object with same AWS key pair. @Oleksii Donoha, so I do not think that's IAM user or policy issue, since JAVA code is fine. I am not sure how to use python to get, so weird.

Comment: @jarmod, aslo in JAVA, `GetObjectAclRequest getObjectAclRequest = new GetObjectAclRequest(bucketname, key);` the `bucketname` I use is `bucket/subfolder` and the key is file name; but in python, the `s3.Bucket('bucket')` must be the root bucket name, I guess if that the reason, Java knows my policy access is start from child path, but python need check if I have access from root path.